# Uncaught TypeError: self.$apply is not a function in Angular1.6

Tags: angularjs

I try to learn angular1.6 and in this example I don't know where I made a mistake.

It suppose, after 3 seconds, to print on the screen and in console log the same text from message variable, when I click on Get Message button.

```js
(function() {
 "use strict";
 angular.module('myApp',[])
    .component('myComponent', {
      template: "<button ng-click='$ctrl.scheduleTask()'>Get Message</button><br><p>Message fetched: {{$ctrl.message}}</p>",
      controller: function() {
        self = this;
        self.scheduleTask = function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            self.$apply(function() {
              self.message = 'Fetched after 3 seconds';
              console.log('message = ' + self.message);
            });
          }, 3000);
        };
      }
    })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <my-component></my-component>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because you do not use $scope. $apply can be used on the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use $scope instead:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp',[])
    .component('myComponent', {
      template: "<button ng-click='$ctrl.scheduleTask()'>Get Message</button><br><p>Message fetched: {{$ctrl.message}}</p>",
      controller: myComponentController
    });

    myComponentController.$inject['$scope'];

    function myComponentController($scope) {
        self = this;
        self.scheduleTask = function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
              self.message = 'Fetched after 3 seconds';
              console.log('message = ' + self.message);
            });
          }, 3000);
        };
      }
})();
```

A more correct way would be to use $timeout:

[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp',[])
    .component('myComponent', {
      template: "<button ng-click='$ctrl.scheduleTask()'>Get Message</button><br><p>Message fetched: {{$ctrl.message}}</p>",
      controller: myComponentController
    });

    myComponentController.$inject['$timeout'];

    function myComponentController($timeout) {
        self = this;
        self.scheduleTask = function() {
          $timeout(function() {
              self.message = 'Fetched after 3 seconds';
              console.log('message = ' + self.message);
          }, 3000, true);
        };
      }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you my friend for help. Looks like you are right :).

Comment: Note that the "true" is non necessary, $timeout will use $apply by default.

Comment: I had to wait 3 minutes to vote u because they told me I can't vote until 3 minutes expire.